# Functional javascript and creating a unique store for each instance of a function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, scope

So I am wondering if there is a technique to create a custom store kind of like redux and use it with multiple instances of a function. I am running into a scope issue with my current approach. The main function will have many functions inside of it with many functions inside of that so I don't want to really have to pass the store down through multiple functions I would really like to just import it into the functions.

The problem is the scope obviously. If I create more than one instance of the controller function they would share the same store values and they wouldn't be unique to one another. I can obviously create the store inside of the main function and pass it down but this gets tedious when you have to pass it down multiple times.

Is there some kind of technique that would allow me to create a unique store for each instance of the controller function and be able to import it instead of pass it throughout the main function and all of its child functions? Right now I am thinking that I am just stuck passing the store down through all functions. Does anyone know of a technique to keep create the store in scope and still be able to import it into functions instead of having to pass it.

Here is a really simple example of the problem [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dawn-3lp86).

```
import controller from './controller';

const button1 = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
const button2 = document.querySelectorAll("button")[1];

const ctl1 = controller();
const ctl2 = controller();

const displayResults = () => {
  const displays = document.querySelectorAll('p')
  displays[0].innerText = 'Controller 1 value is ' + ctl1.getValue()
  displays[1].innerText = 'Controller 2 value is ' + ctl2.getValue()
}

button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ctl1.setValue(ctl1.getValue() + 1);
  displayResults()
});

button2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ctl2.setValue(ctl2.getValue() + 1);
  displayResults()
});
```

controller.js

```
import store from "./store";
import setValue from "./setValue"
import getValue from "./getValue"

const controller = () => {
  
  // I could just create the store here and pass it down to child functions but this is tedious
  // eg: const store = createStore()
  // eg: const setValue = (val) => setValue(store, val)

  // Note this is a very simple example

  return {
    getValue,
    setValue
  };
};

export default controller;
```

setValue.js

```
import store from './store'

const setValue = (val) => store.dispatch({ type: "SET", payload: val });

export default setValue
```

getValue.js

```
import store from './store'

const getValue = () => store.get();

export default getValue
```

store.js

```
const createStore = (reducer, initialState) => {
  let state = initialState;

  const get = () => state;

  const dispatch = (action) => {
    state = reducer(action, state);
  };

  return {
    get,
    dispatch
  };
};

const reducer = (action, state) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialState = 0;

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

export default store;
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for, but would classes and methods be the solution?

Comment: @Barmar It would be the solution but then you are just doing the same thing with `this` as you are passing the store down. I am trying to make my code easier to handle by being able to split up functions and import necessary functions making them pure but with classes it gets though because you are basically binding `this` to everything and inside of the module it isn't as clear as to what `this` refers to.

Comment: Once you get used to writing object-oriented code, keeping track of `this` becomes second nature. With functional programming you have the same problem with keeping track of the scope.

Comment: Something like `export const Store = () => createStore(reducer, 0)` in store.js and `const store = Store()` in the body of `controller`?

Comment: _“... I would really like to just import it into the functions.”_ What do you mean by “import it into the functions”?

Comment: _“If I create more than one instance of the controller function they would share the same store values and they wouldn't be unique to one another.”_ Why don't you create a new store inside the controller each time it is called?

Comment: @AaditMShah I don't know how to be more clear on import it into functions and if you read the question I already address the reason why I don't want to create a new store each in the function and pass it down. Please read the question again.

Comment: "*this gets tedious when you have to pass it down multiple times.*" - it's really not clear what you mean by "pass it down". In your code, the store is not passed around - the one and only usage of the store is inside the controller.

Comment: "*Is there some kind of technique that would allow me to create a unique store for each instance of the controller function and be able to import it*" - no, this is impossible. Imports are global, and don't work with multiple instances.

Answer (score -1):

Use dependency injection

```
const controller = (store = createStore()) => {
```

Your problem is not a scope one.
Once store is 'present' it's in scope.
The problem is you have only create one single store.